# How can I use regex wildcard in assertion?

Tags: regex, nunit, assert

I am trying to do a general `Assert.AreEqual` call on some details in a table header, however I am struggling figuring out how to successfully format the expected results. The return value on the `GetTableHeader` call is as follows:

```
"× •••\r\nAcme Health Fund\r\nBalance Date: 9/27/2017"
```

I ONLY want to assert that the Acme Health Fund text is present. My current call is this:

```
Assert.AreEqual("/.*Acme Health Fund.*/" , GetTableHeader() );
```

How can I format my first parameter in the `AreEqual` call to ONLY expect `"Acme Health Fund"`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NUnit 3 has a much more powerful constraint syntax, I would recommend you use that instead. New features are added to the constraint syntax, not to the old `Assert.AreEqual` style.

Regex is overkill for what you want, all you need to do is assert that the string `Does.Contain` the name.

```
Assert.That(GetTableHeader(), Does.Contain("Acme Health Fund"));
```

If you really need to use a regex, first you don't need to surround it in the slashes and you use the `Does.Match` syntax.

```
Assert.That(GetTableHeader(), Does.Match(".*Acme Health Fund.*"));
```

Note the fix in your regex.

Comment: Rob, thanks so much for your response, I was able to get it to work with both of your solutions, but the Does.Contain is without a doubt a lot easier to use than the Match.